# Pivot dataframe column values into new columns & pivot the remaining columns to rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

`Year` values to become columns & the rest of the columns to become rows. Any ideas?

the data:

```
   Year Propertyval Cumulative
0  1    1224000.00  24000.00
1  2    1248480.00  48480.00
2  3    1273449.60  73449.60
```

Desired format:

```
   Desc          1           2           3
0  Propertyval   1248480.00  1273449.60  1273449.60
1  Cumulative    24000.00    48480.00    73449.60
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df_new = df.pivot_table(columns="Year", values=["Propertyval", "Cumulative"])
```

Update: If you also want to reset the index and change the column name, then this would be more accurate:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df_new = df.pivot_table(columns="Year", values=["Propertyval", "Cumulative"]).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Desc'}).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Thanks for the hint @Tobias P. G.

Comment: This is a much better answer than the other one. +1

Comment: To get the desired columns and index you need to do some additional steps: `df_new = df.pivot_table(columns="Year", values=["Propertyval", "Cumulative"]).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Desc'}).rename_axis(None, axis=1)`

Comment: Yes, you are right. That would be more accurate. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a simpler way, but these steps should do the trick.

```
# Read the sample dataframe from clipboard
df = pd.read_clipboard()
# Transpose the index and columns
df = df.T
# Rename the column based on first row
df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0].astype(int), inplace = True)
# Drop the first row
df.drop(df.index[0], inplace = True)
# Reset index
df = df.reset_index()
# Rename previous index column
df = df.rename(columns={'index':'Desc'})

df
```

Output:

```
    Desc        1.0         2.0         3.0
0   Propertyval 1224000.0   1248480.0   1273449.6
1   Cumulative  24000.0     48480.0     73449.6
```

Comment: You're a legend! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your question please mark the answer as accepted : )